# Coordinator Layout with 2 Recycler Views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to build an android fragment with this layout:

1. Top half of screen is a RecyclerView that scrolls HORIZONTALLY.
2. Bottom half of screen is a RecyclerView that scrolls VERTICALLY.

When the bottom RecyclerView is scrolled toward its bottom, I want the top one to collapse and hide (and open when the bottom view is scrolled to the top).

A coordinator layout would seem to be the answer, but every example I come across uses an AppBarLayout for the top section. The activity containing the fragment already has an app bar displayed; I don't want to modify it.

How would I implement this two RecyclerView setup in a CoordinatorLayout without addressing the app bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `NestedScrollView`, a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation as child of of `NestedScrollView` and add both `RecyclerView`s as children of `LinearLayout`

**sample**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```